# type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast - flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to set a list of string in the shared preferences but for unknown reason, it is throwing up the following error

type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

here is my code

```
  List selectedItems = [];

  setList() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> itemList = selectedItems.map((e) => e.toString()).toList(); // converted int list to string
    List<String> selectedItemsList = await prefs.setStringList('selectedItems', itemList) as List<String>; // error
  }
```

I'm not assigning the bool type value to any variable, so why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

await prefs.setString returns a bool thats why you are facing the error. As reference see https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/setString.html

What you probably wanted to do is use getStringList as so:

```
List<String> selectedItemsList = await prefs.getStringList('selectedItems') as List<String>;
```

or if you really wanted to save the list the line would be:

```
await prefs.setStringList('selectedItems', itemList) as List<String>;
```

Comment: Oh! What a silly mistake I made! Basically I didn't need to store it inside any variable (selectedItemsList) Thanks mate!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you. If the answer helped you consider marking it as accepted for other people.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/setStringList.html), you'll see that `setStringList` returns `Future<bool>`.